# IntlDateFormater pattern to date()/DateTime format

Tags: php, date, datetime, intl

I would like to know if there is something in PHP to convert the format used by IntlDateFormater's pattern (http://php.net/manual/fr/intldateformatter.setpattern.php) to an equivalent (or almost since it looks like some symbols cannot be translated) DateTime/date() format (http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.format.php)

such as 'y-MM-dd' returns 'Y-m-d' for exemple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In that Database format Y-m-d as a default, if you want to different pattern just change in coding part

like: **`$datenew=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['date']));`**

Comment: Sorry but that's not what I would like. As I enlighted in the exemple, i don't want to convert a date from a format to another, i want to convert the format himself to another.